# saddle point of lagrange function (interpretation)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

How to interpret tha following definition for non-linear programming? The triplet $(x^{1},u^{1},v^{1})$ is called a saddle point of Lagrange function $L$ on the region $M\times\mathbb{R}^{J}_{+}\times\mathbb{R}^{K}$ if $$ L(x^{1},u,v)\le L(x^{1},u^{1},v^{1})\le L(x,u^{1},v^{1}),\quad \forall x\in M,u\in \mathbb{R}^{J}_{+},v\in \mathbb{R}^{K} $$

Comment: do the [figures on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point) help?

Comment: No, I do not know how to read the mathematical notes in the definition in normal words.